# R saving with encoding

Tags: r, encoding

I'm trying to plot a graphic with the title: INTERVALS λ.
But the special character λ can't be encoded using ISO8859-1.

Which another encoding I need to choose?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `expression`:

```
plot(1:10, main=expression(paste("INTERVALS ", lambda)))
```